# How can I find out how many users have two medical conditions in my SQL Server database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in my SQL Server database that stores a `UserID`, the name of a medical condition, and a diagnosis date for that medical condition.

```
 UserID          ConditionName        DiagnosisDate
 9038            Hypertension         1971-07-14
 9039            Diabetes             1964-05-13
```

Each user can have multiple medical conditions (i.e. a user with UserID 9038 can have headaches, diabetes, and hypertension).

I want to write a query that finds comorbidity of users.

For instance, I want to know how many people with hypertension also have diabetes.

Answer (score 3):

This shows all users with multible medical conditions:

```
SELECT UserID, COUNT(DISTINCT ConditionName) AS medical_conditions
FROM <TABLE>
GROUP BY UserID
HAVING medical_conditions >= 2;
```

If you want to search for specific medical conditions you could use `IN` and subqueries:

```
SELECT UserID
FROM <TABLE>
WHERE ConditionName = 'Diabetes'
AND UserID IN (SELECT UserID FROM <TABLE> WHERE ConditionName = 'Hypertension');
```

Comment: Actually, I find your first solution weird. What if the user has the same diagnosis on different dates?

Comment: @Radim Bača You're right. I updated the statement. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a subelect:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM YourTable
    WHERE ConditionName = 'Hypertension'
        AND UserID IN
            (
                SELECT UserID FROM YourTable
                    WHERE ConditionName = 'Diabetes'
            );
```

This will give you a count of all records with Hypertension. If a UserID can have the same condition multiple times you have to replace `COUNT(*)` with `COUNT(DISTINCT UserID)`.

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions for this. Using `IN`

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM tab 
WHERE userid IN (SELECT t2.userid FROM tab t2 WHERE t2.ConditionName = 'Hypertension') and 
      userid IN (SELECT t2.userid FROM tab t2 WHERE t2.ConditionName = 'Diabetes')
```

using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM tab t1
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tab t2 WHERE t2.ConditionName = 'Hypertension' AND t2.userid = t1.userid) and 
      EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tab t2 WHERE t2.ConditionName = 'Diabetes' AND t2.userid = t1.userid)
```

using `INTERSECT`

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT userid FROM tab WHERE ConditionName = 'Hypertension'
    INTERSECT
    SELECT userid FROM tab WHERE ConditionName = 'Diabetes'
) x
```

using `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT userid
FROM tab
WHERE ConditionName = 'Diabetes' or ConditionName = 'Hypertension'
GROUP BY userid 
HAVING count(distinct ConditionName) = 2;
```

[dbfiddle demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c56ec89508b3f26dbebeccc055d5b617)

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(1)
from yourTable t
where t.ConditionName = 'hypertension'
    and exists (
        select 1
        from yourTable ref
        where ref.UserId = t.UserId
            and ref.ConditionName = 'diabetes'
    )
```

Comment: One thing to bear in mind with [correlated sub queries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery) is they can be inefficient.

Comment: assuming we know nothing about indexes, my query plan may be equal or even better then Thomas' one, which is so far preferred by viewers